# Notes disappearing right after creation

Tags: notes.app

Sometimes a note in Notes suddenly disappears. It usually (always?) happens just in a few seconds after the creation, while I'm still editing the note.
What causes this kind of behavior and how can I fix this?

(Technical details: OS X 10.8.2, GMail sync is on.)

Answer (score 2):

I observe same behaviour on one of my laptops (both use gmail, but different accounts). One of the solutions is to switch to iCloud sync. Notes stop disappearing, but you can't edit anything while notes are being updated... which happens each time you update something. Apple surely was in the rush to roll out that one.

I haven't figured out the exact reason yet though.. Played with Notes folder IMAP settings to no avail.