# Why are notes not being saved when using Notes on my macbook pro?

Tags: macos, notes.app

I keep having this issue where I will

- Add a note to Notes
- Close the app
- Come back later and open it and its no longer there.

There is no **Save** button on the so assume that once i click "+" and add a note (type something in) and close it that it will be there when i open it up again.

Am i missing something here?

Comment: How are you closing the app?

Comment: just clicking the red X at the top just like any closing any other window

Comment: Do you have iCloud set up?

Comment: @manoftheson - yes i have iCloud setup

Comment: Perhaps the problem lies with iCloud. Go to System Preferences, iCloud and see if Notes is checked in the list in the right pane. And maybe signing out of iCloud and then sign back in. Notes is supposed to auto-save and sync to iCloud as you type notes, so that's what made me think the problem could be there.

Comment: Also this [thread](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/70973/notes-disappearing-right-after-creation?rq=1) seems to be a similar issue.

Comment: I don't have Mountain Lion yet, but does this happen if you simply press `Command+Q` on your keyboard?

Comment: It sounds like Notes are not enabled in your iCloud preferences. Check this by going opening up System Preferences and clocking on the iCloud icon. In the list of enabled iCloud services, make sure that Notes is checked.

Comment: notes IS checked on my icloud preferences

Comment: @leora -This is a shot in the dark... Did you try signing out of iCloud and then sign back in after a restart?

Comment: I've had this same problem. Today, for the first time ever, I lost a "Note" in Apple Notes. I had written an extensive note on my MacBook Pro. I closed the computer, came back an hour later, opened it, and looked in my Notes view panel. The note was completely gone. I can't imagine how it was an iCloud issue, because it disappeared from the very device I used to write it. "Notes" is and was enabled in my iCloud on both my iPhone and my MacBook Pro. It has disappeared from both devices. I did nothing to my knowledge to delete it.

Comment: Why does it sound like that. And why would you think that would stop the notes being saved locally?.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from making sure you've installed all the latest system software updates, try the following to "reset" Notes on your computer:

1. Quit the Notes application.
2. Turn off iCloud Notes sync on *all* your devices (on Mac, in System Preferences > iCloud, and on iOS, in Settings > iCloud).
3. In the Finder, pull down the Go menu, hold down Option to reveal "Library", and choose that.
4. Type `com.apple.Notes` into the search field and then choose the "Name matches" search option that appears.
5. Select the "Library" search scope.
6. The search should show a few folders with names like "com.apple.Notes", "com.apple.Notes.help", and "com.apple.Notes.savedState", and some files named "com.apple.Notes.plist" and "com.apple.Notes.help". Select all of those and drag them to the Trash.
7. Restart the computer.
8. Turn on iCloud Notes on just your computer.
9. Try creating an new note, then check against https://www.icloud.com/#notes to see if notes are being sync'ed successfully.
10. If that works, turn iCloud Notes sync back on again on all your devices.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Will doing this kill any notes already in the Notes.app.

Answer (score 0):

I lost very important notes lately, they just disappear, called Apple and it seems that the problem is with google because notes and gmail do not work well together. now I will create my notes using the icloud but in the mean time I need to contact Google to see whether they can retrieve my notes (which I haven't deleted by the way). anyone got the same problem and did you fix it???? 
PS: what I lost is part of a dissertation :-(

Comment: You've posted this as an answer, which is only for things that directly answer the question asked. If you could follow up with details on what you found from Google that might solidify this, but wouldn't the Mac still have copies of the data locally even if cloud sync never happened? It seems odd the Apple response was so vague.